# Does the Native LoadRunner JMX Monitor support WebLogic 11g (10.3.6)?

Tags: jmx, weblogic11g, loadrunner

I know that the recommended approach is to monitor WebLogic 11g via HP SiteScope.  However, my client hasn't purchased a HP SiteScope license.

I was looking at http://easyloadrunner.blogspot.com/2013/07/how-to-set-up-weblogic-monitor.html 
and it appears that LoadRunner has a native WebLogic JMX monitor.

Does anybody know if it supports WebLogic 11g?

If not, any suggestions short of HP SiteScope?

--Thank you,
--Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your client has LoadRunner past version 8 then a base 500 point SiteScope instance comes as a part of the LoadRunner license.  This is part of the monitoring foundation of the LoadRunner

Comment: James,
 Thank you.  I am double checking with the group that controls the client's LoadRunner install/licenses and will report back.